# How to completely turn off vim's abilty to recode files?

Tags: vim, file-encodings

Every encodings related question I've found is about how to recode files.

However, mine is quite contrary one - is it possible to make vim not to recode files at all? (and how, if so?)

Sometimes it is writing `[converted]` at the status line, and always miss. However, I have my terminal set at the same encoding as edited file, so, I don't need no recoding at all.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
vim -b "myfile.type"
```

to edit in binary mode. You can also set

```
:set binary
```

or if you're lazy like me

```
:se bin
```

before editing a file in vim (applies to the current buffer)

```
:he `binary`


                     *'binary'* *'bin'* *'nobinary'* *'nobin'*
'binary' 'bin'      boolean (default off)
            local to buffer
            {not in Vi}
    This option should be set before editing a binary file.  You can also
    use the |-b| Vim argument.  When this option is switched on a few
    options will be changed (also when it already was on):
        'textwidth'  will be set to 0
        'wrapmargin' will be set to 0
        'modeline'   will be off
        'expandtab'  will be off
    Also, 'fileformat' and 'fileformats' options will not be used, the
    file is read and written like 'fileformat' was "unix" (a single <NL>
    separates lines).
    The 'fileencoding' and 'fileencodings' options will not be used, the
    file is read without conversion.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are editing binary files you want what sehe suggests, `binary`.

If you're editing text files, then you probably need to change [`fileencodings`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27fileencodings%27), or if the problem is that vim hasn't detected the terminal encoding correctly, [`encoding`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27encoding%27).